# How to redirect pages/app folder to subdomain in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js

I search a lot for this on the internet but I don't find any article related to it.

Like I have a folder called pages in the root of my project and below tree is files of it.

```
|   404.js
|   auth.js
|   index.js
|   _app.js
|   _error.js
\---app
        index.js
```

next.js gives default behavior when someone opens `project.local:3000` it will open`index.js` and `project.local:3000/app` it will open `app/index.js` but I want that when someone open `app.project.local:3000` it will open `app/index.js`.

**My Hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1 project.local
127.0.0.1 app.project.local
```

**In short**

I want to redirect `pages/app` folder to `app.project.local` or `app.example.com` in next.js

Answer (score 1):

**Most updated solution**

I found the solution while exploring the documentation on [redirects](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/redirects).

In your Next.js's root folder, create a `vercel.json` file and then insert your redirects as object inside `redirects` array like so:

```js
{
  "redirects": [
    { "source": "/blog", "destination": "https://blog.example.com" }
  ]
}
```

This will only work on production environment. It should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a noobie in next.js (2nd day learning), but I was searching for subdomain support and I found three solutions on this Github issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5682

1. Using zones (still no idea how it works)
2. "Vercel will implement subdomain routing in the near future" (I don't expect to use Vercel in the near future)
3. (my preferred, but not yet tested) An example using custom servers in Next.js: https://github.com/dcangulo/nextjs-subdomain-example
   For #3, see how it was implemented in the `server.js` file

Comment: After testing option 3, I realized that we lose the the "Automatic Static Optimization" feature (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

Also, even with the getServerSideProps, the page takes some time to load for the first time with a given subdomain

Comment: Disregard my last comment about the speed. It was a localhost DNS resolving issue on OSX. I fixed it by adding all my 127.0.0.1 in one line (see https://superuser.com/questions/1189379/chrome-slow-to-resolve-etc-hosts-on-macos-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

With the new "middleware" feature of Next.js, you can rewrite it using a function instead of the rewrite object and keep the `getStaticProps` working.

```js
// middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { getValidSubdomain } from '@/utils/subdomain';

// RegExp for public files
const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/; // Files

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  // Clone the URL
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();

  // Skip public files
  if (PUBLIC_FILE.test(url.pathname) || url.pathname.includes('_next')) return;

  const host = req.headers.get('host');
  const subdomain = getValidSubdomain(host);
  if (subdomain) {
    // Subdomain available, rewriting
    console.log(`>>> Rewriting: ${url.pathname} to /${subdomain}${url.pathname}`);
    url.pathname = `/${subdomain}${url.pathname}`;
  }

  return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
}
```

You can take a look on [nextjs docs about middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) and I've also wrote [this medium article](https://medium.com/@jfbaraky/using-subdomains-as-paths-on-next-js-e5aab5c28c28) with some related content that might help.

Answer (score -1):

NextJS now supports Locales: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing.

You can specify a locale in your config, e.g. `admin` and specify the URL like this:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    // These are all the locales you want to support in
    // your application
    locales: ['en-US', 'admin', 'nl-NL'],
    // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
    // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    // This is a list of locale domains and the default locale they
    // should handle (these are only required when setting up domain routing)
    // Note: subdomains must be included in the domain value to be matched e.g. "fr.example.com".
    domains: [
      {
        domain: 'example.com',
        defaultLocale: 'en-US',
      },
      {
        domain: 'example.nl',
        defaultLocale: 'nl-NL',
      },
      {
        domain: 'admin.example.com',
        defaultLocale: 'admin',
        // an optional http field can also be used to test
        // locale domains locally with http instead of https
        http: true,
      },
    ],
  },
}
```